# Union is Distributive over Intersection with Indexed families of sets Proof Explanation using finite trivial example

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, examples-counterexamples, proof-explanation

[image]

What does the notation
$F_{a,b}$ mean? Is $F_{a,b}$ a set?

What does F$_{a,f(a)}$ mean? Is this F$_{a,f(a)}$ a set?

I have no idea how the lh and rh equality holds. Can I get a finite trivial example of when this equality shown above holds where we define or instantiate some example the set A, B, define what $ B^{A}$ is and define what F$_{a,f(a)}$ is?

Comment: Just an idea...: start paying attention to the nodes of interest and not the *families*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $f \in B^A$ is just that f is an element in the set of all possible functions from $A \to B$.

Then I assume that the set $F_{a,b}$ is the set of all functions such that $f(a) = b$

All the equality follows from the definition of a function, if you see the condition given is equivalent to the definition of a function in terms of binary relations.

Then use as an example the set $A = \{0,1\}, B = \{2,3\}$ and construct all the possible functions from this set (we will have $|B|^{|A|} = 2^2$ functions) and try to prove this equalities.

Comment: The elements a, are the elements in the domain, if you see the condition says that the same element a can not have two different images in the range of $f$ and the intersection should be empty.

Comment: I don't think your interpretation of $F_{a,b}$ is correct. For each pair $(a,b)$ where $a\in A$ and $b \in B$, $F_{a,b}$ is simply some set. Because $f:A \to B$, $f(a) \in B$ and $F_{a,f(a)}$ is also one of these sets.

Comment: It does not specify anything. I'm just saying what it looks like based on the conditions. It's just for him having an interpretation of the equality in that cases. I know the set $F_{a,b}$ is in general, but based on the conditions imposed, it's just considering the subsets of $F_{a,b}$ that behaves as functions. @EikeSchulte